# VBA Execution error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I,m trying to compare a value to three others in three different columns(the first value have to be compared with all the others).
I used this code and i get the execution error 1004 at the if line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub tests_selection()
    Dim SrcWs As Worksheet
    Set SrcWs = Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Dim SrcWs2 As Worksheet
    Set SrcWs2 = Worksheets("Feuil2")

    Dim ResultWs As Worksheet
    Set ResultWs = Worksheets("result")

    Dim rRow As Long
    rRow = 2

    Dim j As Long


      Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In SrcWs.Range("A1:A4700")

            For j = 0 To 4700


         If iCell.Value = SrcWs.Cells(j, 2).Value And iCell.Value = SrcWs.Cells(j, 3) And iCell.Value = SrcWs.Cells(j, 4) Then

        ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 1).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 1).Value
        ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 2).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 2).Value
        ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 1).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 4).Value
        ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 2).Value = SrcWs.Cells(iCell.Row, 5).Value

            rRow = rRow + 1
        End If
            Next j
        Next iCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Do any of the cells you are comparing contain **error values**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Cells(j,2)` will give that error when `j=0`.  There is no Row 0

try:

```
 For j = 1 to 4700
```

Answer (score -1):

you may be after something like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub tests_selection()    
    Dim ResultWs As Worksheet
    Set ResultWs = Worksheets("result")

    Dim rRow As Long
    rRow = 2

    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Feuil1") 'reference Feuil1 worksheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' loop through referenced sheet column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
            If WorksheetFunction.Rept(cell.Value, 4) = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(cell.Resize(, 4).Value)), "") Then ' if current cell value is repeated in adjacent three cells
                ResultWs.Cells(rRow, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Array(cell.Value, _
                                                                  cell.Offset(, 1).Value, _
                                                                  cell.Offset(, 3).Value, _
                                                                  cell.Offset(, 4).Value)
                rRow = rRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get the 450 execution error with this code

Comment: and what line throws the error? BTW isn't that you downvoting, I hope....

Comment: It's not I'm truly grateful for your help.
The line is where you commented "loop through referenced sheet column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one"

Comment: sorry, there was a typo (a comma where there should be a dot). see edited answer and let me know